# Find Code Coverage of active Flows and Process builder

Tags: process-builder, deployment, code-coverage, change-set

How we can check the test coverage of active Process Builders and Flows before deploying them in a Change Set?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the [Deploy Processes and Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_distribute_deploy_active.htm&type=0) and is where the below sample queries and steps come from

*General*

- Utilizes the [FlowTestCoverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flowtestcoverage.htm) object
- Must use Tooling API to query this object
- Flow test coverage requirements don’t apply to flows that have screens
- This only applies (the coverage check) when you select `Deploy processes and flows as active` within `Setup --> Process Automation Settings`.

---

The code coverage "calculation" utilizes two values:

1. Number of all latest flow versions that have test coverage

```
SELECT count_distinct(FlowVersionId) 
FROM FlowTestCoverage
```

2. Number of all active versions with or without test coverage **plus** the inactive versions that are the latest versions that have test coverage.

```
SELECT count_distinct(Id) 
FROM Flow 
WHERE Status = 'Active' AND Id NOT IN ( 
    SELECT FlowVersionId 
    FROM FlowTestCoverage )
```

`+`

```
SELECT count_distinct(FlowVersionId) 
FROM FlowTestCoverage
```

From the above you take `value 1 / value 2` and you get your flow test code coverage.

---

*Example from the documentation*

[image]

---

*Tips*

To get the names of all the active autolaunched flows and process that don't have test coverage, use this:

```
SELECT Definition.DeveloperName
FROM Flow
WHERE Status = 'Active' 
   AND (ProcessType = 'AutolaunchedFlow' 
      OR ProcessType = 'Workflow' 
      OR ProcessType = 'CustomEvent' 
      OR ProcessType = 'InvocableProcess') 
   AND Id NOT IN (SELECT FlowVersionId FROM FlowTestCoverage)
```

Comment: i've always wondered how test coverage works for record-triggered flows with scheduled paths.

Comment: technically if you have an immediate path within that same flow - you can "cover" it per the requirements above (as one element would be covered, but not the scheduled path). I would surmise that the Flow team, based on all their recent updates, probably has some sort of "click, not code" test automation in their mind for the future. As is, we're not really equipped to test them as fully as we'd like and the barrier of needing apex to do it goes against the expectation of deciding to use flow to begin with.

Comment: i'm not convinced that wrapping flow execution in test.startTest/stopTest even exercises the scheduled paths (all _n_ of them)